# Facebook Business Manager not claiming installs which is leading to AppsFlyer not being attributing to them

Tags: facebook-ios-sdk, appsflyer-ios-sdk

I linked Meta with AppsFlyer and seeing no conversions on AppsFlyer side. Their support checked everything and said the following:

> Unfortunately, if Facebook does not claim installs we cannot attribute the same to them. Hence requesting you to kindly get in touch with the Facebook team as to why they are not claiming any installs.

I was expecting AppsFlyer to show conversions since right now it is saying that there no conversions being captured even though AppsFlyer integration is all correct.